# Error when using maven-soapui-extension-plugin, ASSERTION FAILED -> XPathContains assertion failed

Tags: maven, soapui, maven-plugin

I do some test with SoapUI Plugin :

I want to integrate this test with Maven / Jenkins. Test are ok when I used the SoapUI tool. But when I used the following pom file

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.4.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>SoapUITestOnDITx</id>
      <phase>integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test-multi</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <projectFiles>
          <scan>
            <baseDirectory>src/test/ressources</baseDirectory>
            <includes>
              <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>*ToExclude*.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </scan>
        </projectFiles>
        <outputFolder>target/soapui/</outputFolder>
        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
        <useOutputFolderPerProject>true</useOutputFolderPerProject>
        <exportAll>true</exportAll>
        <junitHtmlReport>false</junitHtmlReport>
        <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
        <host>${soapui.host}</host>
        <username>${soapui.username}</username>
        <password>${soapui.password}</password>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But when I run my test with maven` I got the following error :

> ASSERTION FAILED -> XPathContains assertion failed for path [count(//initialInfos/item)>0] : RuntimeException: Trying XBeans path engine... Trying XQRL... Trying delegated path engine... 
>   FAILED on count(//initialInfos/item)>0

whereas my response is good (at least one item is present in the response)

It seems that an dependency is missing but what's the dependency ?

Comment: I believe that it should not really depend on how you run the test i.e., either from `soapui tool` or from `maven`. Behavior should be the same. By the do you want to show how you get the response by updating the question?

Comment: Hello, yes i can add the test report without sensible data, but in fact i used the soapui program (4.6.2) which is an windows programm to generate my tesr case and after maven dependency to run with maven, It's not the same programm